# Data Access in exporting SQL to table to Excel from VB

Tags: sql, vb.net, excel, export

Given the code below, the error that is showing is `Type 'DataAccess' is not defined`. What should I import to VB in order to remove this error?

```
Protected Sub ExportPOS(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DirectEventArgs)
              Handles ExportButton.Click

    Try
    Make Connection

    Dim cnn As DataAccess = New DataAccess(Libatelconnectionstring)
        ........
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this routine (from MSDN) ..

```
Public Sub ConnectToAccess()
    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    ' TODO: Modify the connection string and include any
    ' additional required properties for your database.
    conn.ConnectionString = & _
    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=" & _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\dbFile.mdb"
    Try
       conn.Open()
       ' Insert code to process data.
    Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source")
    Finally
       conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```